# Automatic Logout in Laravel 5

Tags: php, ajax, session, laravel-5, session-cookies

I have read some articles and tutorials about logging out the user when the session expires, but what I want to do this is to ONLY redirect the user to a page where the user MUST **re-enter his/her password again** to continue his/her activity without destroying his/her activity. How can I do that with **ajax request** so it automatically redirect without refreshing the page.

Many developers like me are confused and do not know, how to do this in a right or best way?

Comment: Well, you can create infinity session

Comment: hmm. nice idea...and do you have any suggestion or recommendation about it?

Comment: $lifetime = time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;// one year
Config::set('session.lifetime', $lifetime);

Comment: Please add a full and informative answer sir so I can follow through, not here in comment. Thank you for your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You can set long-time session. To do this you have to edit `config/session.php` and set `lifetime` to value you need in minutes. For example:

```
'lifetime' => 525600, // one year
```

After edit you have to clear config cache with command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: hmm, It is just setting the lifetime of the session sir for 31536000, hmm and it's a `minutes` sir.

Comment: @LaravelMan yes indeed. Sorry. In minutes